# Two submit buttons need to be clicked orderly in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click, submit

I have two submit buttons. I want user to click first submit button then go to the second. Till that second submit button should be disabled waiting for first to be clicked. I don't know how to write JavaScript for this. please help me.

Comment: what is the use of that?

Comment: yes i tried with if else condition

Comment: Please can you show us your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class='first-btn />
<button class='second-btn' disabled />

$(function() {
    $('.first-btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.second-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Something like that should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

frst this would help your 2nd button to be disabled

```
document.getElementById("2ndbutton").disabled = true;
```

get the onclick functioanlaity of ur frst button and if u have ur answer satified then

```
 document.getElementById("2ndbutton").disabled = false;
```

and then you can proceed.